# Inconsistent prediction SVM OpenCV

Tags: opencv, svm

I am implementing a Bag of Words Model using hierarchical K means for clustering and SVM (RBF kernel) for classification of 58 objects using OpenCV 2.4.9. I have been getting inconsistent predictions on the test data set, with >90% accuracy sometimes and <30% accuracy other times, with the same training set, test set, parameters etc, in short on simply re-running the training and test code several times. The prediction was completely stable when I tried on 27 objects.

Could this be due to the randomness in hierarchical k-means clustering, or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: that's not opencv's BOW, or is it ?

Comment: It is the OpenCV's BOW formed using SURF features